# Verb to make something more strict

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to find a suitable verb or verb-phrase to convey the meaning of making something more strict.

Example:

> The regulator ________ the rules governing party A's promotion
>   practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The regulator _______ the rules governing party A's promotion practices.

The word you're looking for is **tighten (up)**.

**[Tighten](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/tighten) (verb):**
If someone in authority tightens a rule, a policy, or a system, they make it *stricter* or more efficient.

**Example:** The Government plans to tighten the economic sanctions currently in place.

✥━━━━✥━━━━✥

You could also say 'strengthen'.

**[Strengthen](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/strengthen) (verb):** 
If a government strengthens laws or measures or if they strengthen, they are made more severe.

**Example:** I am also looking urgently at how we can strengthen the law.

✥━━━━✥━━━━✥